# how to return null datetime

Tags: date, time, null

I know such questions are repeated but I did not get any result.I must change helical date to Gregorian date and this is my method

```
public static DateTime ShamsiToMiladi(string shmasi)
{
    DateTime? Dt = null;
    if (shmasi != "")
    {
        System.Globalization.PersianCalendar persian = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
        char[] spChar = { '/' };
        string[] splited_shamsi = shmasi.Split(spChar, 3);
        Dt = persian.ToDateTime(int.Parse(splited_shamsi[0]), int.Parse(splited_shamsi[1]), int.Parse(splited_shamsi[2]), 12, 12, 12, 12);

    }
    return Dt;
}
```

sahmsi is a parameter that comes from a textbox.what do i return Dt? 
thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since DateTime is actually a structure built upon a long integer, it cannot be assigned a null value.

But if you need to have that option, declare it as a nullable DateTime thusly:

```
DateTime? ThisDate = null;
```

If you do return a nullable DateTime, your caller will have to check for a null value before using as a regular DateTime in expressions.

As a general rule, a newly-declared regular DateTime has a value of DateTime.MinValue ('01/01/0000'), and you can test for that, instead.

Comment: thanks. I test this:DateTime Dt = DateTime.MinValue;but i receive this error SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Comment: The SQL DateTime has a different range.   When you write it back to the database, you'll have to do something like:  `MyTable[currentRow][dateColumn] = (dt == DateTime.MinValue) ? DbNull.Value : dt ;`

Comment: Thank u Curt .But it makes me more confused.

Comment: I think it would be easiest just to return a DateTime? instead of a DateTime--then you can use the body of your current method with no other changes.   Just change the declaration to: `public static DateTime? ShamsiToMiladi(string shmasi)`.

Comment: I tested it already and it returns a error in insert method form page "can not convert system.date time? to system.date time" AND i change insert method to member.Insert(txtName.Text, txtCellphone.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtCode.Text,(DateTime)Utils.ShamsiToMiladi(txtDate.Text),
txtEmail.Text ); BUT i receive This error : Nullable object must have a value.

Comment: @Noora        That's what I was trying to explain.  You cannot freely convert from a DateTime? to a DateTime:  you have to test whether it's null before making the assignment, because a regular DateTime cannot take a null value.    Maybe this will help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx